# Find the cipher used

Tags: word, cipher, knowledge, lateral-thinking

Each of the following lines were said by various famous personalities. Each line corresponds to one person. There is no relation between these lines. After obtaining the names of these people, A 6 letter word can be formed. This is the name  of a technology developed fairly recently. Applying a layer of cipher on this word produces the Latin word from which the English word for reddish yellow, or tawny has originated from. What is the cipher used?

> I'm not an amazing cook. But I can follow a recipe!
>
> Tact is the knack of making a point without making an enemy.
>
> And miles to go before I sleep.
>
> How often have I said that when you have excluded the impossible whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth.
>
> Love is a serious mental disease.
>
> It Ain't hard to tell, I'm the East Coast overdose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Latin word we are looking for is most likely

> *fulvus*.

Working backwards, we can find that

> using a Caesar cipher with an offset of 3, we can get CRISRP, which is close enough to a recent technology, CRISPR-Cas9.

That suggests that the way we should have got here is by

> Taking the first letter of each person's name: **R**achel McAdams, **I**saac Newton (wrong), **R**obert Frost, **S**herlock Holmes, **P**lato and **C**ristopher George Latore Wallace, the birth name of The Notorious B.I.G.

Comment: Great work! On a scale of 1-10 how difficult do you think this was?

Answer (score 3):

**Partial answer**

1. > [Rachel McAdams](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/rachel_mcadams_436941).
2. > [Howard Newton, but often misattributed to Isaac Newton](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2018/07/18/tact/).
3. > [Robert Frost](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/42891/stopping-by-woods-on-a-snowy-evening). (The inclusion of the 2nd quote in the 3rd appears to be a mistake.)
4. > Sherlock Holmes. (Famous enough that I couldn't be bothered to find a link.)
5. > [Plato](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/79545-love-is-a-serious-mental-disease), whose [real name is unknown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plato#Name).
6. > [This guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Notorious_B.I.G.), [apparently](https://genius.com/The-notorious-big-party-and-bullshit-lyrics).

*the Latin word from which the English word for reddish yellow, or tawny has originated from*

> Presumably we're looking for a 6-letter word here, so [ochra](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ochre#Etymology_1) can't be the answer ... I'm trying to think of another synonym for this type of colour.